# DRF: API Design

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using the ContentType framework and GenericForeignKeys with Django. When embedding the `content_object` into an object field for serialization– is it better to embed it as a field named `content_object`? Or as a named field that's injected?

So for example, let's say I have notifications with a loosely associated object:

Should I:

- Inject a `type` field for the client to consume, with types like `FRIEND`, `ALERT` and so on.
- Inject a relevant object, like `friend`, `alert`

OR

- Infer the type from the content_type field. However this will be unreadable, so the client will simply need to know this enum.
- Injet the relevant `content_object` field but keep it named `content_object`, switching off of the `content_type` field.